# Dividing up a space evenly within a GTK# Bin

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I have a custom Bin, and I wish to divide its space into two columns of equal width separated by a VSeparator.  I've tried using both a Table and an HBox, but it doesn't do the trick.  I don't know how to tell gtk to divide the space evenly no matter what the contents of the two columns.  Setting homogeneous to true works, but that also causes the VSeparator to get way too much space.

Comment: Grid (Table is deprecated) and HBox are correct, as is GtkPaned. Consider setting the hexpand and halign properties of the controls that you want to grow until you get the correct results, perhaps throwing a SizeGroup there if all else fails. And if even that doesn't work, then you can make your own *GtkContainer*. GtkBin is not what you want; Bin is explicitly for having a *single* child.

Comment: You saved me....SizeGroup did the trick.  Bin was what I wanted...its single child was the table/hbox.